# Solving the problem with the "Indexing data" window while editing

Tags: qgis, editing, indexing

When trying to edit a vector layer using node tool, I get constantly the next message:

[image: Indexing data]

Normally it appears once at the beginning of the edition and then it doesn't show any more, but now I get it constantly. It blinks very fast and I can't even edit the line.

I've tried to save this layer again as another shapefile. I have closed and re-opened the software. I have disabled all the plugins (just in case it's a matter of memory or rendering). None of this tries solved anything.

It is not the only layer where this happen, so I think the problem is not a corrupted file (or maybe everything is corrupted).

Anybody knows why this is happening and how to solve it?

(QGIS 2.8.6 on Windows 7)

Comment: Try `Layer Properties > General > Create spatial index`. Note that you're using quite an old version of QGIS so not sure if this option is available...

Comment: I've tried your solution, which is enabled in the version I'm working with, but the problem persists. I've tried the solution proposed by Matthias and it helps a little, but still doesn't solve completely the problem.

Comment: I have the same problem as user above this is repeatedly checking every layer i have in QGIS every time i going to edit. It only started when I added names to my shapes or features . It now got so bad its preventing editing. I recently installed with a later version but had not seen this before. QGIS version
3.12.1-București
QGIS code revision
121cc00ff0
Compiled against Qt
5.11.2
Running against Qt
5.11.2
Compiled against GDAL/OGR
3.0.4
Running against GDAL/OGR
3.0.4
Compiled against GEOS
3.8.1-CAPI-1.13.3
Running against GEOS
3.8.1-CAPI-1.13.3
Compiled against SQLite
3.29.0
Running against S

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's caused by snapping. I guess you could disable that.

Upgrading QGIS might be the better option though, I'm quite sure it has been solved in newer versions.

---

Update: Even when they turned off snapping, it continued working in the background. The solution was to open "advanced options" in the snapping menu and disable it for all the layers.

Comment: I know I'm gonna sound very newbie, but: ¿if I upgrade my QGIS version to the last LTR version, can I keep working with my project or I'm gonna have problems? (I ask that because the deadline of the project I'm working in is in a couple of weeks, so I'm afraid of having to adjust too many things)

Comment: Normally it's not much trouble. But to be on the safe side, install the version in parallel and try to work on a copy of your project file first.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I think I'm going to try it. Moreover, the solution you proposed (disable snapping) worked just at the beginning. I imagine there isn't anything better...
The fact is that some time ago, this problem wasn't there. I don't know what could have happened.

Comment: Finally it was a snapping problem, you were right! The problem was that something went wrong and even if I turned off snapping, it continued working in the background. So what i've done is selecting "advanced options" in the snapping menu and disable it for all the layers and everything worked fine!

Answer (score 2):

It can also be caused by Show Feature Count in the Layers Panel. Uncheck it, if it is checked.

Comment: I have this panel already unchecked. I don't know what can cause this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Just to confirm that in QGIS 3.14, this still persists (from a snapping-indexing perspective at least anyways).